Explicit lower bound for $|2^W - 3^L|$ from Baker's theorem
There is a question here on MSE (The lower bound of $|3^p - 2^q|$ - how to derive from Baker's theorem?) regarding how to deduce the form of the lower bound for the difference between a power of 2 and a power of 3, using Baker's theorem on linear forms in logarithms. There's also a question on MathOverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428396/simple-estimation-of-difference-of-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3), which gets closer to actual application, but there are still constants floating around in the final answer.
I'm looking for something more explicit, in which the "effectively computable constants" are actually computed.
Let $D=|2^W-3^L|$
What can we say about a lower bound for $D$, in terms of $L$? Like, if I know something about the size of $L$, say $L>10^9$, I'd like to be able to say that $D$ is no smaller than... an actual number. How can I do this?

Dang, why the downvote? If there's something I can do to improve the question, please let me know.
